# Как сделать поиск по родителю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, требуется сделать поиск по родителю, у меня есть 2 родителя с классом middle и в каждом из них блок .timer который содержит свой атрибут data-timer с индивидуальным значением. Мне надо сделать так чтобы атрибут брался не с последнего блока middle для обоих, а чтобы брался атрибут только от родителя .middle в который завернут блок timer с тем же атрибутом

```
       <div class="middle">
            <div class="time1" data-timer="2017-12-26T12:57:40"></div>
            </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <div class="time2" data-timer="2018-12-26T12:57:40"></div>
            </div>

     $(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date($('.time1').attr('data-timer'));
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds1').text(sec);
$('.minutes1').text(min);
$('.hours1').text(hur);
$('.days1').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();
});


         $(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date($('.time2').attr('data-timer'));
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds2').text(sec);
$('.minutes2').text(min);
$('.hours2').text(hur);
$('.days2').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();
});
```

Comment: логично, если вы в цикле назначете `eventDate` то по его завершению, оно будет иметь значение последнего элемента. Весь код мб имеет смысл завернуть в этот цикл? не особо ясно что вы вообще делаете там.

Comment: @teran Посмотрите пожалуйста я обновил код может станет понятнее

Comment: То есть я не хочу плодить кусок кода даты, чтобы понять в нем функциональные классы, дописав ко второму блоку 2 или к третьему 3